# Local Notification (repeat) fired after new install of app

Tags: iphone, ios, local, uilocalnotification, repeat

in my app I am using local notifications and often they have a repeat interval set.

The problem is, when the user deletes the app and reinstalls it, the repeat notifications start firing again. 
Is there a fix for this problem? Will the following suggestion from another user work? :

> you can use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]; only at first launch, so that "old" notification will be cancelled....(I haven't tried that)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

> you can use [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
>   cancelAllLocalNotifications]; only at first launch, so that "old"
>   notification will be cancelled...

This is not your solution. This will cancel all your already scheduled notification every time when your didFinishLaunching method will called. So before applying above solution there should be one more check. Store a value in NSUserDefauls for checking that you are installing application again after deleting.

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"Notification"]){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:Yes ForKey:@"Notification"];
}
```

This will prevent from canceling all notifications every time.